# class won't let me create a new object

Tags: asp.net

Hi I'm unable to create a new object that is a subclass I think that's what you call it it saying virtual isn't allowed what must I do to correct this here is my code.

```
public class PagerBuilder {
    private virtual class PagerLink
    {
        public string Title { get; set;}
        public int PageNo { get; set; }
        public string Class { get;set;}
    }

    private readonly List<PagerLink> _pagerLinks = new List<PagerLink>();
    private readonly string _urlTemplate;
    public PagerBuilder(string urlTemplate)
    {
        _urlTemplate = urlTemplate;
    }

    public string PagerClass { get;set;}

    public void AddPage(string title, int pageNo)
    {
        AddPage(title, pageNo, string.Empty);
    }

    public void AddPage(string title, int pageNo, string itemClass)
    {
        PagerLink link = new PagerLink();

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to set a readonly string in your constructor?

Comment: The compiler is saying that it's my virtual declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would move `PagerLink` outside of the `PagerBuilder` class and define it separately (in a new file as well).

Second, you don't need virtual to subclass `PagerLink` (It's not even valid, in fact). If you want it to be abstract, use the `abstract` keyword instead, but this code won't compile (at `PagerLink link = new PagerLink()` until you define a concrete implementation of `PagerLink`. You don't need to use `abstract` to inherit from `PagerLink`, though. Just do this:

```
public class CustomPagerLink: PagerLink
{
   //Subclass implementation
}
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing what you said and I created it a new class outside I was trying to implement this code from an MVC script to .net 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove `virtual` from your class definition.

```
private class PagerLink
{
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public string Class { get;set;}
}
```